# Can Cohen's d be used for distributions that are not normal?

Tags: distributions, normality-assumption, effect-size, cohens-d

Can Cohen's d be used for distributions that are not normal? Or is it used only to compare normal distributions?

Answer (score 4):

You can do anything. The question is whether it would make sense. When the mean difference would be a poor reflection of the difference between groups, Cohen's *d* will also fail.

There are modifications to Cohen's *d* that you can use in such instances and other instances when Cohen's *d* would be problematic. Algina and co have some suggestions https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26487051